# $p$-value and type II error

Tags: p-value, type-i-and-ii-errors

I performed Mann-Whitney U test and Fisher´s exact test as a univariate analysis (association) between independent and dependent variables.
Now, I would like to create a multivariate model, including all those variables that were significant ($p$-value) on univariate analysis.

Does the increase of $p$-value as inclusion criterion for multivariate model (e.g. set at 0.2 instead of "standard" 0.05) decrease the probability of type II error?